# How to delete entire row when A1:A100000 columns are duplicated

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I have to filter quite big data (102858 rows, 9 columns).

The idea is that between these rows (URL addresses) are a lot of duplicates. A1:A102000 contains URL addresses with and without comments. For instance, 1 row have URL address (A1), comment (B1), date (C1) and so on. A2 and C2 are the same as A1 (URL), but blank in B2, C2, B3, C3. I need to get list of unique URL with comments (or without comments if there are no duplicate)

I found VBA code which remove entire row when later A1:A100000 cells are dublicated. However it works only with small number of rows. I just get "Run-time error 1004"

```
Sub RemoveDupe()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRange As Range
Dim lCount As Long

Set rRange = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
lCount = rRange.Rows.Count

For lCount = lCount To 1 Step -1
    With rRange.Cells(lCount, 1)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRange, .Value) > 1 Then
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next lCount
End Sub
```

Have you got any suggestion?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If this is 2003 you're probably having issues because of limits on the number of rows you can have. Is there anything else with that error message? If you have a later version, have you tried the `Remove Duplicates` feature?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the Remove Duplicates feature on the Data ribbon.  You can select which columns to consider, which in your scenario would be just column A.